# Concatenate all dataframe columns into a single column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, concatenation

I have a dataframe that looks roughly like:

```
        01/01/19 02/01/19 03/01/19 04/01/19
hour                                                                           
1.0     27.08    47.73    54.24    10.0 
2.0     26.06    49.53    46.09    22.0
...
24.0    12.0     34.0     22.0     40.0
```

I'd like to reduce its dimension to a single column with a proper date index concatenating all the columns. Is there a smart pandas way to do it?

Expected result... something like:

```
01/01/19 00:00:00   27.08
01/01/19 01:00:00   26.08
...
01/01/19 23:00:00   12.00
02/01/19 00:00:00   47.73
02/01/19 01:00:00   49.53
...
02/01/19 23:00:00   34.00
...
```

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: What is a proper date index? What happens to the hours index after concatenation?

Comment: @Erfan updated the question

Comment: @cs95 the hours go into a datetimeindex, I have a grid with date columns and hour rows, I'd like a single column with a full time stamp index and its value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stack and then fix the index using `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
u = df.stack()  
u.index = (pd.to_datetime(u.index.get_level_values(1), dayfirst=True) 
         + pd.to_timedelta(u.index.get_level_values(0) - 1, unit='h'))

u.sort_index()

2019-01-01 00:00:00    27.08
2019-01-01 01:00:00    26.06
2019-01-01 23:00:00    12.00
2019-01-02 00:00:00    47.73
2019-01-02 01:00:00    49.53
2019-01-02 23:00:00    34.00
2019-01-03 00:00:00    54.24
2019-01-03 01:00:00    46.09
2019-01-03 23:00:00    22.00
2019-01-04 00:00:00    10.00
2019-01-04 01:00:00    22.00
2019-01-04 23:00:00    40.00
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Bread and butter piece of code, was trying to solve this with `melt`

Comment: @Erfan Melt was an option but the hours index would have been lost. So I decided to go with stack which lines up the index and columns nicely :)